# how to pass data between one component to another which is on same router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular5

**app.component.html**

I have two components 
1) ResetPassword
2)  LoginComponent
on the same router-outlet.

on successfully resetting the password. I'm redirecting to login component.
How do I pass data from ResetPassword to LoginComponent?

I tried using subscribe method to do this but that is not working.

Can someone help me fix this.

**LoginService**

```
export class LoginService{

 private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('');
    currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

setResetPassword(message: string) {
        this.messageSource.next(message)
    } 
}
```

**LoginComponent**

```
OnInit{

this._loginService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => {

    if (message !== undefined && message !== "") {
                this.toastr.info(message);
    }
});

}
```

**ResetComponent**

```
OnInit(){

this._loginService.setResetPassword("Password Changed Successfully");

}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction here's your answer. Use `@Input` and `@Output`

Comment: You have two options : either service and OnInit Lifecycle hook or Input and Output event emitters.

Answer (score 1):

To pass data between component basically we use `@Input` and `@Output`, But in your case, I don't think this is the good approach.

So you can simply pass your `message` as **query params string** (If data is **not confidential**) from reset password to Login component and then display as per requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code in **LoginService.**

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

   currentMessage = new EventEmitter();

   setResetPassword(message: string) {
      this.currentMessage.emit(message)
   } 
}
```

And move your **ResetComponent** code in submit function.

```
resetPassword() {
   this._loginService.setResetPassword("Password Changed Successfully");
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Change onInit ot ngOnInit it working for me

For your reference check the following code

```
<div><a></a></div>
<div><b></b></div>
```

```
@Component({
    selector: 'b',
    template: `<input [(ngModel)]="data" /> 
                <button (click)="update()">update</button> `,
})
export class B implements OnInit {

    data

    constructor(public loginService: LoginService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    update() {
        this.loginService.update(this.data)
    }

}
```

```
@Component({
    selector: 'a',
    template: `<h1> {{data}}</h1> `,
})
export class A implements OnInit {

    data

    constructor(public loginService: LoginService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loginService.currentMessage.subscribe((data) => {
            this.data = data;
        })
    }
}
```

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class LoginService {

    private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('');
    currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

    update(message: string) {
        this.messageSource.next(message)
    }
}
```