# Data showing as undefined when I am trying to pass data from parent component to child components

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to pass data from parent component to child components, but I am getting data is `undefined`,
In my below code

**parent component**

here part_data I have declared in service

```js
this._PartService.GetDataValues(this.search.item, this.search.filter_type, release_part).subscribe(
  result => {
    this.resultData = result;
    this._PartService.part_data = this.resultData.data
  })
```

**child component**

Here I am using observer

```js
this.searchService.observer.subscribe(search => {
  this.part = search.item;
  this.specification = this._PartService.part_data.partMasterDataCompleteList[0];
})
```

Here I am getting `PartMasterDataCompleteList[0] is undefined`

Comment: How are you sending data? are you using `@input`?

Comment: use If before accessing value

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response, I am not using @input, I am just sending data through property, In my case I am sending part_data..

Comment: I actually want to use @input, so can you please let me know how to use It in my case

Comment: Can you post your `@Component({...})` code?

Comment: @Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})                                                                                                                         
 This is for parent component

Comment: show your data for-->  this._PartService.part_data.

Comment: Can you add a stackblitz ?

Comment: Please check stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6yjmr3.... Header.component is my parent component and part-detail is my child component

Answer (score 1):

Use this as the child component:-

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-detail.component.css']
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() hero: Hero;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

When you need to feed data to the component, use the below code:-

```
<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>
```

The hero property is `@Input` which receives data from the outer environment.

For more information, refer to Angular tutorial:-

> https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3

Comment: Can you please update full code or create a StackBlitz so that we can help you?

Comment: Please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6yjmr3....                                               Header.component is my parent component and part-detail is my child component

Comment: Kindly, put the code in a running state. It is very hard to infer the code in this way. Thanks

Comment: I am getting errors, so its little hard to put in running state..By seeing those 2 components can you just tell me how to use @Input...Thanks

Comment: Are you even passing the data from the parent component or are you using a service to get the data. The link that I shared is very informative, kindly go through the same. it will be very helpful to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your data in sub component and get using `@Input` method.

There is one other way to pass data from one component to other component.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166353/how-to-pass-data-between-one-component-to-another-which-is-on-same-router-outlet/51166493#51166493)